# Decrypt a des string in to plain text

Tags: php, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I need to decrypt a string encrypted with des algorithm. How can I do in PHP? I have real test cases as follows:

```
key ='0123456789abcdef'
encryptedValue = '88C10F0B8C084E5F'; //hex value
decodedValue = '2020202039353538';  // this is hex
```

I've tried

```
$keyValue ='0123456789abcdef';
$encryptedValue = '88C10F0B8C084E5F'; //hex value
$decodedValue = '2020202039353538';  // this is hex

$decryptedData = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_DES, $keyValue, $encryptedValue , 'ecb');
var_dump($decryptedData);
var_dump($decodedValue);
```

**Output of decryptedData is null.** I checked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10747435/7544279). Please suggest me a solution.

Update:2017 Jan 18:
Many people are suggeting me not use des or mcrypt. **I need to decrypt this because my API provider reponds me with this algorithm.** **And about `mcrypt_decrypt` function, I did not find an alternative**. Now please suggest me more.

I tried according to @duskwuff, I made modifications as.

```
$decryptedData = mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_DES, $keyValue, hex2bin($encryptedValue) 'ecb');
var_dump(bin2hex($decryptedData));
```

Output is **empty string** which is obviously binary representation of `bool false`

For you convenience I want to share the result of crypto calculator.[image]
I'm getting this **warning** as well:`Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): Key of size 16 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of size 8 supported in /var/www/html/encdec/enc.phtml on line 13`

Comment: You might wanna look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php). This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Comment: Why are you using DES?  It's outdated and insecure.

Also, it looks like your key value might be a bit too short.

Comment: @JoeP. DES key length is 56 bits. `"0123456789abcdef"` is either 64 or 128, depending on whether it's being treated as hex or a raw string.

Comment: @PaulKaram  Please check my updated question.

Comment: @JoeP. Please check my updated question

Comment: @duskwuff is it so that des key should be 56 bits? I'll research on that. But this is what they provided me and gave me  an example of decoded string using the same key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using following code:

```
$keyValue ='0123456789abcdef'; //hex value
$encryptedOrderId = '88C10F0B8C084E5F'; //hex value
$decodeValueByOnlineTool = '2020202039353538';  // this is hex
$opensslDecrypt = openssl_decrypt(  hex2bin($encryptedOrderId)  , 'des-ecb' , hex2bin($keyValue) , OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING , '' );
var_dump($opensslDecrypt);
```

Answer (score 2):

The values you're passing into `mcrypt_decrypt()` look like they're intended to be a representation of hexadecimal data, not passed in directly. Use `hex2bin()` on the inputs to convert them to binary data, and `bin2hex()` to convert the output back to the expected representation.

Also, stop using mcrypt. It's old and broken, and has been removed from PHP 7.2.

Comment: I did as you said still some issue. Please check my updates.